# how to send data to server with the same TCP connection using ajax or JS trick

Tags: ajax, tcp, streaming, packets

I know how to keep a connection indifinetely open server side to stream continuously data to javascript.
BUT
I do not know how to send data reusing the same TCP from browser to server.
so there is not the 3 way handshake and only 2 tcp packets.
I know it is possible but I do not how to do it : use xmlhttprequest? or script tag ajax ?
can you tell me how to do it.

thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

How about using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets).